# Display full name (first + last name) on index/show template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am newbie to Phoenix and Elixir but I try hard to learn it. It may be a stupidly easy question but I don't know how to display the full name of the book's author on the book's index/show page.

Here is my query in inventory/book.ex

```rb
def get_author_full_name(author) do
  from b in "books",
  join: a in "authors",
  on: b.author_id == a.id,
  where: a.id == ^author,
  select: %{id: a.id, name: concat(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name)}
end
```

Custom SQL:

```rb
defmodule CustomSQLFunctions do
  defmacro concat(left, mid, right) do
    quote do
      fragment("concat(?, ?, ?)", unquote(left), unquote(mid), unquote(right))
    end
  end
end
```

And in inventory.ex

```rb
def display_author_full_name do
  Author
  |> Author.get_author_full_name()
  |> Repo.all()
end
```

In book_controller.ex

```rb
plug :load_author_full_name when action in [:index, :show]
defp load_author_full_name(conn, _) do
  assign(conn, :books, Bookstore.Inventory.display_author_full_name ())
end
```

I was following instruction from the book Programming Phoenix 1.4 to display a dropdown list of categories with some small changes to suit my case. Can someone guide me on how to display the full name of the book's author? I don't know if I wrote matching the case code and what to put in the view and index/show pages.

Comment: Just to clarify: is there a reason why you don't wish to use separate variables for the first name and last name?  In other words, why not just do your "concatenation" in the view layer?

Comment: Also... I am confused by your `get_author_full_name/1` function... I don't understand why you are joining on the `books` table when all you want to get is the author's name -- I don't think any join is required.  The function name is misleading: you're retrieving a list of authors (or possibly a list of authors joined with book data).   You could just rely on the `preload` option to avoid the N+1 problem -- assuming you have schemas for `Book` and `Author`, it might look like 
`from(b in Book, preload: [:authors])  |> Repo.all()`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am new to elixir and phoenix and I thought it might be a good idea to do something "like" it is in the book. I came up with something like: `<% fullname = book.author.first_name <> " " <> book.author.last_name %>` in index/show.html.eex and then: `<td><%= fullname %></td>`. But I guess it's not an ideal solution.

Comment: It's great to try things out -- that's how you learn!  In this case you could also do `<td><%= book.author.first_name %> <%= book.author.last_name %></td>`.  However, there will be times when you need to apply some business logic somewhere to consistently modify the data before you use it in a view (e.g. something more complex than concatenation).  Often a dedicated module or function is the place to handle that -- some languages do this sort of thing in "service classes"; Phoenix uses "contexts" as a place where such manipulations can occur before data is sent to a view.

Comment: I took your question seriously and gave a try to code it in the view. Here is the result. In `book_view.ex` I got:
`def full_name(%Writers.Author{first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name}) do
    [first_name, last_name]
    |> Enum.reject(&(&1 == ""))
    |> Enum.join(" ")
  end` and in index.html.eex: `<td><%= full_name(book.author) %></td>`